# C# TaskWhenAll on method which is returing result depending on awaited call

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

i'm trying to make this code works in async way, but i got some doubts.

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync(string inputA, string inputB)
{
    var result = await AnotherGetAsync(inputA, inputB)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result.Enabled
        ? inputB
        : string.Empty;
}
```

I got some string input collection, and i would like to run this method on them.
Then i would do Task.WhenAll, and filter for non empty strings.

But it won't be async as inside the method i'm already awaiting for the result right?

Comment: This method is async and so is `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Can you share the input collection and what you've tried so far?

Comment: It would be async, but as far as i can tell, it will just run async forever, since you're calling GetAsync inside GetAsync... ConfigureAwait will cause the calling thread to not necessarily return on the same thread, but i don't think this implementation can ever end. correct me if i'm wrong. As i expected, i ran it in the interactive console, and immediately got a stackoverflow exception (kinda fitting isn't it)

Comment: This probably can't compile at all. `result` can only be a string which doesn't have an `Enabled` property. You *can't* have another `GetAsync(string,string)` method that returns a different type as even in C# 8, overloading doesn't take the return type into account. You'd either get a compilation error for `result.Enabled` or for having two identical `GetAsync` methods

Comment: Sorry guys, it's my first post, and i put same method names ;)
AnotherGetAsync method is returning an object with some properties, and then depending on Enabled property i'm returning correct value from GetAsync.

But i thought that as inside GetAsync i'm already waiting for the result then Task.WhenAll will run those methods one, after another. Not at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed the real question is:

> If a single item is awaited inside method A, will this run sequential if I use `Task.WhenAll` for a range of items calling method A?

They will be run simultaneous with `Task.WhenAll`.
Perhaps it is best explained with an example:

```
void Main()
{
    Test().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task<bool> CheckEmpty(string input)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
}

private async Task Test()
{
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "1",
        null,
        "2",
        ""
    };

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // This takes aprox 4 * 200ms == 800ms to complete.
    foreach (var itm in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await CheckEmpty(itm));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine();
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // This takes aprox 200ms to complete.
    var tasks = list.Select(itm => CheckEmpty(itm));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Runs all at once.
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

My test results:

```
False
True
False
True
00:00:00.8006182

False
True
False
True
00:00:00.2017568
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like i still need to get some more knowledge on asynchronous programming :)

Answer (score 2):

If we break this down:

```
AnotherGetAsync(inputA, inputB)
```

Returns a `Task`. Using the `await` keyword implicitly returns *another* `Task` to the code calling `GetAsync(string inputA, string inputB)`.

Using the `await` keyword will free up the current thread, which is what makes the code asynchronous.

once the `Task` returned by `AnotherGetAsync(inputA, inputB)` is complete, `result` will be set to that `Task.Result`.

The remainder of the method will then resume:

```
return result.Enabled
    ? inputB
    : string.Empty;
```

Setting the `Task.Result` of the `Task` returned from `GetAsync`.

If `GetAsync` is to be run multiple times, you can use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for each resulting `Task` to complete:

```
Task.WhenAll(yourStringCollection.Select(s => GetAsync(s, "another string"));
```

`Task.WhenAll` itself returns another `Task` that will complete when all the `GetAsync` tasks have completed:

```
var strings = await Task.WhenAll(yourStringCollection.Select(s => GetAsync(s, "another string"));
var nonEmptyStrings = strings.Where(s => s != string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it **will** be async. When you `await` a task inside an async method, the task will be awaited when the async method is invoked. Here is your example simplified, using explicit variables for the created tasks:

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    var innerTask = InnerGetAsync();
    var result = await innerTask;
    var stringResult = result.ToString();
    return stringResult;
}
```

Later you create two tasks by invoking the `GetAsync()` method:

```
var task1 = GetAsync();
var task2 = GetAsync();
```

At this point the two tasks are running concurrently. Each one has invoked internally the `InnerGetAsync()` method, which means that the two `innerTask`s are also up and running, and awaited. Any code that follows the `await` will not run before the `innerTask` is completed.

The completion of each outer task (task1 and task2) is dependent on the completion of its `innerTask`. Any code that will `await task1`, will also implicitly `await innerTask` as well.

After creating the two tasks, you combine them with `Task.WhenAll`, then do something else, then `await` the combined task, and finally process the results:

```
Task<string[]> whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
DoSomethingElse();
string[] results = await whenAllTask;
ProcessResults(results);
```

It is important that the `DoSomethingElse()` method will run before the two tasks are completed. So at this point three things will be happening concurrently, the `DoSomethingElse()` and the two active tasks. The `await` inside the `GetAsync()` method is local to this method, and does not mean that the generated outer task will be automatically awaited upon creation. To process the results of `task1` and `task2` you must first `await` them as well.